# Layout Needs Manual refresh. Looks like it can't load external js

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using JSF2 with Primefaces3.4.2 I have created a layout in layoutComplex.xhtml as below:

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE8" />
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type" />
            <title>PrimeFaces - ShowCase</title>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jscolor.js" target="head" />
        <script type="text/javascript">  
    function handleValidateRequest(xhr, status, args) {  
        //alert("");
        //jscolor.addEvent(window, 'load', jscolor.init);
    }  
</script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit id="left" position="west" size="300" resizable="true"
                closable="true" collapsible="true" header="Options" minSize="200">
                <h:form>
                    <p:slideMenu style="width:235px;margin-left:-3px;margin-top:-6px;"
                        id="tree">
                        <p:submenu label="Product" icon="ui-icon-play">
                            <p:menuitem value="test color picker"
                                update=":centerContentPanel " action="#{navigationBean.doNav}"
                                oncomplete="handleValidateRequest(xhr, status, args)"
                                icon="ui-icon-arrow-4-diag">
                                <f:param name="urlParam" value="colorPicker" />
                            </p:menuitem>
                        </p:submenu>
                    </p:slideMenu>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center">

                <p:panel header="Colors">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                        <h:inputText class="color">
                            <p:ajax event="change" update="osssutcolor" />
                        </h:inputText>
                        <h:outputText style="display: none" id="osssutcolor" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>

                <h:form id="centerContentPanel">
                    <ui:include src="#{navigationBean.pageName}.xhtml" />
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>


    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Yes,I can dynamically change the source of centerContentPanel without refreshing the whole page and just the centerContentPanel i.e for on click of menuitem present in the layoutComplex.xhtml,and then the colorPicker page's content will be displayed in the centerContenPanel. But issue is: I added a colorpicker.js in the layoutComplex.xhtml head and hope it can work when update centerContent, but actually, it's not working  .. 
but after refresh all page by press F5 ,it works fine as I expected. Why? How can i fix this?
Following is colorPicker.xhtml:

```
   <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jscolor.js" target="head" />
        <p:panel header="Colors">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                <h:inputText class="color">
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="osssutcolor" />
                </h:inputText>
                <h:outputText style="display: none" id="osssutcolor" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>

</ui:composition>
```

and NavigationBean.java

```
package com.singtel.eshop.control;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class NavigationBean {
    private String pageName = "blank";
    public NavigationBean() {
    }
    public void doNav() {
        String urlStr = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("urlParam");
        this.pageName = urlStr;
    }
    public String getPageName() {
        return pageName;
    }
    public void setPageName(String pageName) {
        this.pageName = pageName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the js file also? and do you see any error in the javacript console of your browser? Can you also add how do you call the colorpicker.js functions from the loaded xhtml files?

Comment: I updated code and paste . load from  .../layoutComplex.jsf first and i found that the js works nice ,but after click item and update centercontent , the other colorpicker inputbox display but out of work , at same time . previous colorpicker also work ...
I Suppose wether the update action modified the DOM, So  the live bindings are re-evaluated. thus ,  refresh whole page ,can bingding ID correct.

Comment: In your colorPicker xhtml can you add a script which calls jscolor.init function. Seems like jscolor is only initialized after window load event and it is not called after the end of the ajax call.

Comment: Yes.I favor your view on this issue.But how to do that ? add a script which calls jscolor.init function ? How can i do  ..
the js website here :http://jscolor.com/
actually i use js from here.but i don't know how to invoke it's init fuction by script in colorPicker.xml...Can you give some advices? Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the jscolor.init after ajax call too. Seems like it is being called right after page load and needs to be called after your ajax call or inside your component. You can achieve this by calling jscolor.init in your colorPicker.xhtml file like this.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jscolor.js" target="head" />
<script>
            jscolor.init;
        </script>
        <p:panel header="Colors">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                <h:inputText class="color">
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="osssutcolor" />
                </h:inputText>
                <h:outputText style="display: none" id="osssutcolor" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: base on your advice ,i enhanced and implement in this way .
 <code><script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function setDateReadonly() {
        alert("into ");
var myPicker = new jscolor.color(document.getElementById('centerContentPanel:myField1'), {})
 alert("out");
});       
 </script>

</code>
Many thanks .