# Jscolor stops working after first postback of fresh deploy, but continues to work after postback of a reload

Tags: javascript, jsf, jscolor

Could anyone tell me something helpful to the following behavior in JSF with Jscolor component?

I have got this simple xhtml code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
        <h:head>
            <title>RDFa test</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>    
            <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jscolor/jscolor.js"/>
            <h:form>
                <h:commandButton class="color" value="ok"/>
                <h:commandButton value="server" type="submit" action="#{testBean.tmp}"/>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </html>
```

TestBean.java:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {
    public TestBean() {}

    public void tmp() {
        System.out.println("SERVER!");
    }   
}
```

If I do the first deployment and click on the "server" button, the Jscolor will go away and does not work (it is like destroying the javascript on the page)! If I then reload the page and click on the same button, the Jscolor works normally. There's no exception in server log, nor any error in Firebug JS console. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

**EDIT:**
I am not the only developer, who straggles with this issue. Here tyhand describes exactly, what I mean: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1641380

COuld you please explain me what is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: No I did not. Maybe "error" is not the right word - the IDE throws no exception, the Firebug no error. The problem is: the JsColor component does not work (in this example the command button is only a button with no function - no color...). Any idea?

Comment: Okay, I fixed the question. Is the code provided so far really the SSCCE? Didn't you oversimplify it too much without actually testing it? The invalid `class` attribute (it should have been `styleClass`) is a good hint that this code is untested. I can recognize and explain the problem for ajax buttons which update themselves without re-executing the script, but the button in the code snippet is not an ajax button.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for fixing the question and the hint. I have replaced the invalid class attribute by styleClass but it is not a solution: now it is SSCCE and after the first postback it still not works...

Comment: It looks like this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228632/layout-needs-manual-refresh-looks-like-it-cant-load-external-js

But I don't understand the solution - what should I do? Maybe there is some optimalization and by the first postback the JSF calls the action as AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. It is so easy!!! I have to add before all input fields with class='color' (binding fileds to the jscolor) this code:

```
<script>jscolor.init();</script>
```

Comment: I had a related issue; jscolor was not working after setting `$('body').html(newHtml);`. I simply solved it by calling `jscolor.init()` afterwards. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Haha, thank you for solving this! I had the same issue after a jQuery.load() function.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use jscolor inside a repeater that was inside an update panel in a custom DNN module.

None of the various solutions I saw here worked...I finally figured it out.

At top of HTML in your usercontrol:
Use <dnn:DNNJsInclude..... /> to point to your jscolor.js file, then add

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function pageLoad(sender, args) {

    $(".jscolor").each(function (i, obj) {

        var picker = new jscolor(obj);

    });
};
```